# setting to 0 the future file descriptor before calling socket()

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor

In socket programming in C, I saw in a simple client/server example that before calling `socket()`, the `int` variable that will hold the socket file descriptor is set to 0.

```
int fds;
fds = 0;
fds = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (fds == -1) {
     perror("Socket():");
     exit(-1);
}
```

Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

No, none. `socket` will always return a value.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't access the `fds` variable before writing to it, there is no real reason for that.

If, however, you have a certain distance between definition and assignment, it might be useful to set `fds` to an "invalid" value such as `-1`:

```
int fds = -1;
[ lots of code which might accidentally use fds ]
fds = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (fds == -1) {
     perror("Socket():");
     exit(-1);
}
```

Now, imagine I accidentally use `fds` in the code somewhere between `int fds = -1;` and `fds = socket(...)`, I definitely get an error because of that invalid usage.

On the other hand, if I didn't set `fds` to `-1`, it could have any value, maybe a value which is a valid FD in our process. If I do a `read()` on this file - or even worse: a write()`, I might end with corrupted data structures.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense. `socket` will still set `fds`.

Comment: @Abbondanza Of course it does. But only after the erroneus use of the wrong `fds` value.

Comment: However, this is not a *reasonable* approach to capture such errors. So if there is a reason (as the OP asked) for a programmer to produce such code, it simply is that he or she is not good at programming. A better programmer would condense declaration and definition into one statement (`int fds = socket(...)`) or leave `fds` undefined and use the compiler option `-Wuninitialized`.

Comment: @Abbondanza Condensing would indeed be *the* way to go. Leaving undefined and relying on a compiler option, however, would IMHO be only the 3rd option.